# Eclipse E4: How do I get the CSS style that would apply to an MPart?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I've got a `Composite` inside an Eclipse E4 application, and I'd like it to have the same background color as a default `MPart` does, according to the theme (which I don't want to be controlling, I just want to consume).

The `Composite` in question in contained within another `Composite` with a different background color, so the color cannot be directly inherited.

How can I (programmatically or declaratively) retrieve the CSS `background-color` styling that applies to an `MPart`, in order to apply it to my `Composite`?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to assign a CSS class to the `Composite` and style it in the CSS.

Assign the class using:

```java
Composite composite = ....

WidgetElement.setCSSClass(composite, "MyComposite");
```

You will need to add dependencies on the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt` and 
`org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core` plugins to use `WidgetElement`. It is also marked as restricted but it is OK to use.

In your CSS you can style it the same as the `MPart` using:

```css
.MPart,
.MyComposite
{
  background-colour: xxxxx;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449 for your responses. I should have mentioned that there is a differently-colored composite in between. I'll change my question to make that clearer.

Comment: Changed answer to use CSS classes

Comment: OK, I should also explain that I don't want to be controlling the theme color, I just want to use it as-is - for example, I'm in the IDE and just want to run with the MPart background-color that is in the current theme.

Comment: You can probably use the background color (after styling) of the top level Composite in the MPart - do you have access to that Composite?